# Часть строковых данных в порядке, часть - кракозябры

Tags: sql-server

У меня есть база (SQL Server). Часть строковых данных в порядке, часть - кракозябры. Скорее всего, что везде, где возможно была выставлена кодировка UTF-8, а данные летели иногда в CP-1251. Хотелось бы услышать ваши мысли по поводу того, можно ли как-то спасти такие данные? Да? Нет? Почему? Я новичок в работе с SQL Server. Из опыта по MySQL помню, что там можно задать кодировку (сравнение) на базу, таблицу (и вроде даже на столбец). Можно ли так в SQL сервере? Поможет ли это?

Comment: Данные спасти можно, только не в коем случае не играйтесь с кодировкой на "живой базе". Мне приходилось сталкиваться с похожим случаем, но я решал проблему не средствами SQL сервера, а писал свою программу, которая перегнала все данные из испорченной базы в заранее созданную новую, попутно исправляя кодировку в местах, где это было необходимо.

Comment: @SoulOFTrue Понял. Какой метод для определения кодировки использовали в своей программе?